# How to improve performance of lists with multi-lookups

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, performance

I have a list that includes several lookup fields. Some of these are simple lookups (only one value allowed), others are multi-lookups (the "allow multiple values" checkbox is selected).

I have noticed that these multi-lookup columns have a big impact on performance, retrieving views that include multi-lookups are much slower than views with single lookups.

Are there techniques to make these views faster? For example server side settings, indexing options, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option is not to show these columns in the view.

If you need to show the data and have high performance, then you might consider adding a readonly text column to show and have an event receiver populate that with the values from the multivalue lookup column.